# Covariance of stochastic process

Tags: covariance, stochastic-processes, covariance-matrix, stochastic-calculus

I have the following stochastic differential equation

$dX_t=\kappa\left [ \theta-X_t\right ]dt + \Sigma d W_{t}$

I derived formula for $X_t$ which is in the following form

$X_{t}=\theta+e^{-\kappa t}\left ( X_0-\theta  \right )+\Sigma e^{-\kappa t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{\kappa s}dW_{s} \qquad  \forall t \in\left [ 0,T \right ]$

Now I want to derive covariance. The formula for covariance is in the following form

$Cov(X_t,X_r)=E\left [ \left ( X_t- E\left [ X_t \right ] \right )\left ( X_r -E\left [ X_r \right ]\right ) \right ] $

$=E\left [ \left ( \Sigma e^{-\kappa t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{\kappa s}dW_{s}\right ) \left ( \Sigma e^{-\kappa r}\int_{0}^{r}e^{\kappa u}dW_{u} \right )\right ] $

$=\Sigma e^{-\kappa (t+r)}\Sigma ^{\top} E\left [ \left ( \int_{0}^{t}e^{\kappa s}dW_{s} \right ) \left ( \int_{0}^{r}e^{\kappa u}dW_{u} \right )\right ]$

And using Using Itô isometry it follows that

$Cov(X_t,X_r)=\Sigma e^{-\kappa (t+r)}\Sigma ^{\top} \int_{0}^{t}e^{\kappa s}ds$

But result in the book is in the following form

$Cov(X_t,X_r)=\int_{0}^{t}e^{-\kappa s} \Sigma \Sigma ^{\top} {e^{-\kappa s}}^{\top} ds$

Can someone please tell me where I made a mistake?